# Under ZF + DC + AD, is it known what the properties are of the Hartogs number for $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ for some $\kappa>\aleph_0$?

Tags: set-theory, determinacy

It is a well-known result by Woodin that the Hartogs number $h(\mathbb{R})$ (more commonly known as $\Theta$) is a Woodin cardinal (in HOD) assuming ZF + AD + DC. This is equivalent to $h(\mathcal{P}(\aleph_0))$. However, I was wondering the simple question of this very generalization; specifically the following question:

$$\exists\kappa\exists\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}(\aleph_\alpha\not\leq^*|\mathcal{P}(\kappa)|)?$$

If $\kappa$ satisfies the inner quantification of this formula, one could say $\kappa$ satisfies the Hartogs property (or $\mathrm{H}(\kappa)$).

In, ZF + AD + DC what properties does $\mathrm{H}(\aleph_1)$ have? What about even larger ordinals? What about in HOD, or even assuming $V=\mathrm{HOD}?$
(The original question was quickly shown true)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  ZF+DC+AD implies that $\aleph_1 $ does not embed into $P(\aleph_0)$.  ZF implies that for every set there is a well-order that does not embed.  Isn't that Hartogs' theorem?

Comment: I don't really see your reasons for not understanding the question; I was asking for a generalized $\Theta$. When did I claim $\aleph_1$ embeds into $P(\aleph_0)$? By $\aleph_\alpha\not\leq|\mathcal{P}(\kappa)|$, I meant there is no surjection from $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ onto $\omega_\alpha$.

Comment: You should use standard notation then.

Comment: Ok, I will in the future. What is the standard notation?

Comment: (And the answer is of course yes. )

Comment: $|A|\le|B| $ means that $A $ injects into $B $.  $|A|\le^*|B|$ means that either $A $ is empty or else $B $ surjects onto $A $, but this notation is less common than the one for injections so you should probably remind the reader of its meaning the first time it shows up.

Comment: To amplify the answer given by Andrés's parenthetical comment: It is a theorem of ZF, that, for every set $X$, there exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that there is no surjection from $X$ onto $\alpha$. To prove it, just notice that a surjection $f:X\to\alpha$ gives rise to a one-one map $\alpha\to\mathcal P(X)$, namely $\xi\mapsto f^{-1}[\{\xi\}]$; then apply Hartogs's theorem.

Comment: Ok, I will rephrase the question.

Comment: ZF+AD+AC implies that the empty set is not empty.

Comment: More generally, AD seems like a red herring to this entire question. And it seems to me that the question is made by poorly understanding the structure of the universe of set theory without choice.

Comment: Let me also add that using $\nleq$ to denote "no surjection" is inconsistent with the standard notation, which would be $\nleq^*$. Using Hartogs to denote the least ordinal that there is no function from a set onto that ordinal is also in contrary to standard terminology of set theory, where this is either not explicitly named, or named "the Lindenbaum number (of a set)", although I was the one to introduce this term. In some cases, $\Theta$ is used to denote the Lindenbaum of the power set, or a variant of such definition.

Comment: In any case Hartogs proved every set has an ordinal which cannot be mapped into the set injectively, and Lindenbaum proved the corresponding theorem for surjections (there is an ordinal that the set cannot be mapped onto). So the question, as I said, seems to stem from poor understanding of the structure of a choiceless universe.

Comment: My bad, I meant ZF+AD+DC. Also, the question is what properties $H(\aleph_1)$ has.

Comment: I meant to edit it to $h(\kappa)$. Also, are you talking about $H_\kappa$?

Comment: The question in the title is still not what you want.

Comment: The notation of this question is a total mess. You're overloading $H(\kappa)$, which is often used for sets whose transitive closure has size $<\kappa$; you're still using the name Hartogs property, even though it is not the right name; and what does it even mean in the first displayed formula that $\kappa$ has an existential quantifier? Then you move to HOD which is a model of choice, making the whole thing even more confused.

Comment: And did I mention already that "all sets satisfy the so-called Hartogs property"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit confused, but I *think* what you're asking is:

> Let $S(\alpha)$ be the supremum of all the ordinals onto which $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$ surjects. What can we say about e.g. $S(\omega_1)$?

*(And your original question was whether $S(\alpha)$ always exists, which it does.)* **If** this is your question, I think it's a good one (if it's not then you need to clarify what your question is), and the key fact is **Moschovakis' coding lemma** *(see around page 397 in [Kanamori's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540888666))*:

> (ZF+AD) Suppose there is a surjection from $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ to $\alpha$. Then there is a surejction from $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ to $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$.

(There are also non-AD versions of the coding lemma.) This gives us:

> Corollary (ZF+AD): Suppose $S(\omega)>\alpha$ (so $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ surjects onto $\alpha$). Then $S(\omega)=S(\alpha)$.
>
> *That is: for $\alpha<\Theta$, $S(\alpha)=\Theta$. In particular, $S(\omega_1)=\Theta$ and $\Theta$ is a limit ordinal, since the powerset of a cardinal always surjects onto that cardinal's successor.*

Proof: Since $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ surjects onto $\alpha$, by the coding lemma $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ surjects onto $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$. But if $\beta<S(\alpha)$ this means that $\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$ surjects onto $\beta$, so by composing surjections we get that $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ surjects onto $\beta$, so $\beta<S(\omega)$. (And conversely clearly $S(\omega)\le S(\alpha)$.)

---

Having calculated $S(\alpha)$ up to $\Theta$, it's worth saying a bit at this point about $\Theta$ itself. The coding lemma shows that $\Theta$ is a limit, but this isn't the end of the story - lots more can be said. For example, Solovay showed that $\Theta=\omega_\Theta$ and that $\Theta$ has uncountable cofinality. Additional hypotheses give you further "largeness" properties of $\Theta$, and in particular "$\Theta$ is regular" plays an important role in inner model theory (see e.g. [this paper of Sargsyan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.2712.pdf)).

Note that it is quite possible that $\Theta$ is *not* regular - the regularity of $\Theta$ is a strong assumption, especially in conjunction with stronger determinacy principles (e.g. AD$_\mathbb{R}$). In fact, $\Theta$ can have cofinality $\omega$. Interestingly, this cannot occur if $V=L(\mathbb{R})$ - Solovay showed that in $ZF+AD+V=L(\mathbb{R})$, $\Theta$ is regular.

Comment: Noah, you should indicate that the cofinality of $\Theta $ can be countable, just not in $L (\mathbb R) $.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Sure, I'll add a bit at the end.